# Can't display images using Angular 5

Tags: angular, image, http-status-code-404

If I simply hardcode the image filepath into the img src attribute like so...

```
img src="../../../../Resources/homeImage.png"
```

...the Gods are happy with me and the image gets shown to one and all.

But..........

If I create a component property called homeImage with the same value using either of the following,

```
public homeImage = "../../../../Resources/homeImage.png"  
public homeImage = "http://localhost:54270/Resources/homeImage.png"
```

then try to use the homeImage property like either of the following,

```
img src="{{homeImage}}"  
img [src]="homeImage"
```

both methods resolve to the resource but I get 404 Not found.

It's been a few hours, and I now have a major headache.
Any light shed on this dark place would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Do one thing build with ng build, check what directories u get. And then u can put relative path to image after seeing directories structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the image inside assets folder and use relative path to refer it. Assets folder is generally under `app/src`

```
<img src="assets/img/1.jpg" alt="image">
```

Comment: I created an assets folder in the root and placed the image there.
I pointed the homeImage property to that location.
I get the same results

Comment: Check the network tab and the request URL is correct

Comment: It sure looks right.
http://localhost:54270/assets/homeImage.png

But even if I paste this url into the browser, it returns not found

Comment: Im building in VS and the folder structure I started with isnt quite app/src. Its more like ClientApp/app
Should I put assets in ClientApp/app?

Comment: This doesnt seem to fly. If I can harcode the path that includes a Resources folder instead of an assets folder and the image is displayed, why would I need to use an assets folder when Im trying to be dynamic. This isnt a mobile app, if that makes a difference. At least not yet

Answer (score 0):

I added Resources folder with my image into the dist folder then
create the property like so...
public homeImage = "/dist/Resources/homeImage.png"
Then I got to use homeImage in the src attribute of my img element

Answer (score 0):

> you should use `assets` folder to store your static assets, images
>   etc.

if you want to store images and static assets in another directory you need to tell CLI about it by making an entry in `assets` array of the angular.json file and you need to ensure that it is on the same level as the `assets` folder. i.e create a custom folder under app

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
               src/Resources
            ],
```

and you can provide absolute path instead of the relative path because CLI knows about it

```
public url = "Resources/homeImage.png";
```

Comment: Hi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.